# out of memory xamarin.android.common.target in visual studio 2017 mac

Tags: xamarin.android, out-of-memory, visual-studio-2017

Today I update my visual studio 2017 preview, but now I can't debug any android project, only i can debug IOS project,
the issue is 
out of memory in xamarin.android.common.target
and the bellow is the output of the warning

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Warning: Out of memory
  at (wrapper alloc) System.Object:AllocVector (intptr,intptr)
  at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.MsfDirectory..ctor (Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbReader reader, Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFileHeader head, Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess bits) [0x00066] in <2ddd3e947fff4a79b757d1cc8412bc70>:0 
  at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFunctions (System.IO.Stream read, Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.BitAccess bits, System.Boolean readAllStrings) [0x00016] in <2ddd3e947fff4a79b757d1cc8412bc70>:0 
  at Microsoft.Cci.Pdb.PdbFile.LoadFunctions (System.IO.Stream read, System.Boolean readAllStrings) [0x0000c] in <2ddd3e947fff4a79b757d1cc8412bc70>:0 
  at Pdb2Mdb.Converter.Convert (System.String filename) [0x00033] in <2ddd3e947fff4a79b757d1cc8412bc70>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertDebuggingFiles.Execute () [0x0006a] in <2ddd3e947fff4a79b757d1cc8412bc70>:0  (GotnetMezna)

note: "GotnetMezna" is my project name

Comment: Make sure you use Visual Studio 2017 stable release, https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/ Preview builds can be unstable and are not recommended.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi I updated and solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use Visual Studio 2017 stable release,

http://visualstudio.com/vs

Preview builds can be unstable and are not recommended.